# Motion of a Particle Newton's Second Law

Tags: vector-spaces, vectors, physics, classical-mechanics

There exists a particle of mass $m$ acted on by a force $F = kt^2$. $k$ is a constant and $t$ is time. The particle starts at $x=0$ with constant velocity $u$. Find the acceleration, velocity and position of the particle.

Attempt:

$kt^2 = m\ddot x$, so $\ddot x = \frac{kt^2}{m}$ is the acceleration.

Integrating and using initial conditions $\dot x(0)=u$ and $x(0)=0$ gives $\dot x = \frac{kt^3}{3m} + u$ and $x = \frac{kt^4}{12m}+ut$.

Is this correct ?

Comment: Sry(!), it’s fine. There is some info left out in the problem: the force applies in straight line and the initial velocity is collinear with the (emerging) force. You may want to reformulate the problem, saying like both force and initial velocity apply along x-axis, or that the motion is 1-dimensional.

Comment: @TeM Thanks, just wanted to make sure.

Comment: @WindSoul Okay thanks for your help, it just seemed too simple / easy that I thought I was wrong